# Config is not loading & getting-error -> configuration-property-MAX_CONNECTIONS-is-not-defined

Tags: node.js, node-config

I have a `node.js` app & have some configurations based on the environment. So decided to use

https://www.npmjs.com/package/config

In accordance, I created a folder named `config` at the root level of the app. The folder structure looks like as below

```
app
  -config
   --default.json
   --local.json
   --qa.json
   --prod.json
  -src
   --routes
    ---products.ts
```

this is my local.json & default.json

```
{
 "MAX_CONNECTIONS" : 100
}
```

in product.ts

```
import { get } from 'config';
// code emitted for brievty 
const allowedConnectionsLimit = get<number>('MAX_CONNECTIONS'); //also tried with get("MAX_CONNECTIONS")
```

But this keeps on throwing the error

> **error-configuration-property-MAX_CONNECTIONS-is-not-defined**

Things tried

- uninstalled config & @types/config
- reinstalled config & @types/config
- moved the config folder inside src
- rebooted the app
- cross checked the filename & the variable name

even then this is throwing the error

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to import config object and use config.get to read configuration value.
When you use `import { get } from 'config';` config library resolves incorrect `this` variable and therefore can't read the value.

```
import config from 'config';
// code emitted for brievty 
const allowedConnectionsLimit = config.get<number>('MAX_CONNECTIONS');
```